# IIS Blazor App (Intranet) require entering Windows Credentials

Tags: c#, .net, iis, blazor

I have a couple of .NET 5.0 Blazor applications deployed to IIS 10 on a Windows Server for intranet traffic. These applications have Windows Auth enabled and allowed the user to view the site with their Windows Credentials, which would automatically be passed to the Blazor site (ie. it could show them their domain account information). Recently, without changing anything on IIS or related to any configuration, the sites started asking users to manually enter their Windows Credentials, which shouldn't be happening.

I created a new Blazor app and deployed the scaffolded app to IIS, and this didn't require entering Windows Credentials. I also then migrated the existing code to the scaffolded app to test what may be the root cause, and kept deploying the changes to IIS incrementally. I eventually had the entire codebase moved to the scaffolded app, and it still worked without requiring credentials. We have our applications deployed under the Default Web Site, so I then removed the old application and created a new one, and it started asking for credentials again.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be the cause of this?

- Windows Auth is enabled for the project.
- Windows Auth is enabled on IIS

```cs
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddServerSideBlazor();
services.AddSignalR(e => {
    e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 65536;
});

services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
services.AddAuthorization();

...

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: "the sites started asking users to manually enter their Windows Credentials", do you mean that web browsers prompt for credentials? What type of browsers? Keep in mind that's key information you should never miss in such questions.

Comment: Confirm in IIS that anonymous authentication is disabled.

Comment: Anonymous Auth is disabled. And yeah, I mean that it prompts for credentials. Normal usage is Chrome, but I've tested with Edge as well (and I have never visited the site before with Edge, so that can't be a cache issue). I also tested from a different computer, that I've never visited the site, or the server before, and it still prompted for credentials.

Comment: Are the permissions on the folder correct? if not, that could cause the prompt of the credentials, as the Windows Credentials don't have permission

Comment: Permissions are set so that IIS_IUSRS needs access to the folder to serve the content. If that user doesn't have access, IIS throws and error when you try to visit the site. So that access is there. Additionally, I'm an Admin, so I have even higher access rights on the folder by default.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this issue ? I'm having the same issue. My previous intranet website that didn't use blazor, I had IIS anonymous authentication and windows authentication enabled and everything worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

(Old question, but I thought I'd take a shot...)

Have you tried adding that site to your computers trusted sites in the internet options?

Go to Internet Options --> Trusted Sites --> Sites and enter the full URL including https://

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/add-trusted-sites-in-the-windows-10-control-panel/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31500642)